# Unity просит поставить запятую в 16 строке 9 символа

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У юнити похоже красные дни, ибо оно просит поставить запятую на пустом месте
Любые попытки исправить приводят к той же просьбе поставить запятую
Даже создав новый скрипт юнити самозабвенно просит поставить запятую, а если поставить её, то просит убрать эту зловредную запятую
Помогите пожалуйста

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AccesLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public Button actionButton;
    bool opend false;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }




    public void Action()
    {
        if (opend)
        {
            anim.SetBool("open", false);
            opend = false;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("open", true);
            opend = true;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        actionButton.SetActive(true);
    }

    void onTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        actionButton.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Полностью скопированный текст ошибки
Assets\Scripts\AccesLevel.cs(9,16): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Comment: Тогда уже в 16 символе 9 строки, а не в 9 символе 16 строки, как в названии вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в строке:

```
bool opend false;
```

Нужно исправить:

```
bool opend = false;
```

Либо просто

```
bool opend;
```

Булева переменная и так `false` по умолчанию.